# how to pass data between pages in Nextjs 13 with router.push()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to programmatically pass data between pages when navigating with `useRouter`'s `push()` method. The following code redirects me to the url `http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]`, but I was expecting it to take me to `http://localhost:3000/home?userid=deepeshdm&orderid=12345`. Why does it do this, and how do I fix it?

```
// app/page.js

"use client"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = () => {
    router.push({
      pathname: '/home',
      query: { userid: 'deepeshdm', orderid: '12345' },
    });
  };

  return (
   <>
   <h1 align="center"> Root Page </h1>  <br/>
   <button onClick={handleClick}> GO HOME </button>  <br/>
   </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It appears for Next.js 13, `router.push()` only accepts a string.
[image]

It looks like they dropped `pathname` and `query` for read-only hooks.
[image]

The way around this is to use template literal string interpolation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
router.push(`/home?userid=${userid}&orderid=${orderid}`);
```

I hope this helps.