# error: TypeError: path.startsWith is not a function in NEXT.JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am building a next.js eccomerce app and i am trying to go to product page with data dynamically with useRouter but it is throwing the error. I have no idea why this is happening please guide me how can i solve this??

[image]

code is

**it is working fine with this line
**

```
      router.push(`/hoodies/${curElm.title}`)
```

**and throwing error with this
**

```
const goToProductPage = (curElm) => {

      router.push({
        pathname: `/hoodies/${curElm.title}`,
        query: { data : curElm }
      });
    
  };
```

I want to send the object(curElm) data with navigation to the other page.

please guide me
thank you

Comment: I can't find documentation where you can pass an object to `router.push`? https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerpush Maybe nextjs changed the API?

Comment: here it is sir https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#with-url-object

Comment: It looks like it's because you're using the documentation for the "pages" router inside the "app" folder. Refer to this documentation instead https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router

Comment: so tell me sir what can i do in this matter? i am not getting anything

Comment: [Follow their instructions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter)

Comment: there is nothing in the documentation how can i send an object/data with navigation sir??

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. [_"The `query` object has been removed and is replaced by `useSearchParams()`"_](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#migrating-from-nextrouter). Make sure to read their [migration guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration)

Comment: thank you sir now i got it sorry as i am new to next.js and learning. one last thing sir i did not find any of the solution for data passing still as next.js did not provide any documentation for this. can you please guide me what should i do next??

Comment: What do you mean by "data passing"?

Comment: like i have products in my eccomerce app i want that when user clicks any product it should navigate to the new page and show the all details of that particular product for that i have to pass data with router while navigation??

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374380/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-nextjs-13-with-router-push?

Comment: i tried this but sorry this is also not working. but thank you for your great help sir.

Comment: Please make a new question showing the issue. Make sure the code shown is a text-based [mcve]. (No images of code please)

Comment: ok sir i am doing

Comment: sir please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325630/how-can-i-pass-data-with-navigation-in-dynamic-routing-next-js